# Combine function call and simple string using ngClass

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular and I wish to create a div couple of time using ngFor. All divs has the same class, which were getting from a function call, plus a 'no-margin' class on the last div.

My html template looks like this:

```
<div class="brick" 
*ngFor="let iteration of numberOfBricks; let lastBrick = last"
[ngClass]="{ongoingTimelineEventView.getEventClass(), 'no-margin':lastBrick}"
[ngStyle]="{'width.px':brickPropotion.width,'height.px':brickPropotion.height}">
</div>
```

However that doesn't work and I get a compiler error. The problem is with the ngClass, I guess because I'm calling a function inside "{}" expression. Any idea how can I get this code to work?

Thanks!

Comment: what is errror ?

Comment: check the answer that will help you

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create function in you ts and return class name from there only , below is code for the same , if you want to apply multiple class than you should return multiple class string from function like `'class1 class2'`

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div [ngClass]="getClass('layout1')">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
getClass(divId) {
    if (this.selectedLayout === 'layout1') {
      return divId === 'div1' ? 'col-lg-8' : 'col-lg-4';
    } else if (this.selectedLayout === 'layout2') {
      return 'col-lg-6';
    } else if (this.selectedLayout === 'layout3') {
      return divId === 'div1' ? 'col-lg-4' : 'col-lg-8';
    } else if (this.selectedLayout === 'layout4') {
      return 'col-lg-4';
    } else if (this.selectedLayout === 'layout5') {
      return 'col-lg-12';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

***All divs has the same class, which were getting from a function call***:

You just call a function in `ngClass` and return any `className` from that function to all `div's`.

***Plus a 'no-margin' class on the last div:***

send `last` as `parameter` in `function` and if it is `true` you can add `no-margin` or `what ever` class you require. `getClass(lastBrick)`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from 'ng2-modal'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Modal],
  template: `
  <div class="brick" 
*ngFor="let iteration of numberOfBricks; let lastBrick = last"
[ngClass]="{ 'blue': true; 'no-margin': lastBrick }"> Brick {{iteration}}
</div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  numberOfBricks = [1,2,3,4,5]

}
```

[**Here is a working DEMO for your code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJbyKd2sujfc24lgM7qw?p=preview)

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I wanted to avoid creating a function that generates class names. Can you think of a way to achieve the goal you implemented using only ngClass?

Comment: @RiskX, I updated my answer and plunker, Please check now

Comment: seems like you forgot to update you html part , and then it will lead to my answer only if you do that

Comment: I updated my `html` and its completely different to your `answer`.

Comment: even that `function` also I m not using

Comment: its by mistake , apologies for that reverted downvote

Comment: yeah its ok. no problem. :-)